# How to display custom address fields value to frontend in woocommerce My-account -> Addresses?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added a custom field called "Nick Name" to billing and shipping address form.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'add_nickname_field' );

function add_nickname_field( $fields ) {

    $fields['nickname_field']   = array(
        'label'        => 'Nick Name',
        'required'     => false,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'my-custom-class' ),
        'priority'     => 10,
        'placeholder'  => '',
    );
    return $fields;

}

// This will show the nick name field on edit-user screen
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'admin_address_field' );

function admin_address_field( $admin_fields ) {

    $admin_fields['billing']['fields']['billing_nickname_field'] = array(
        'label' => 'Nick Name',
        'description' => '',
    );

    $admin_fields['shipping']['fields']['shipping_nickname_field'] = array(
        'label' => 'Nick Name',
        'description' => '',
    );

    return $admin_fields;

}
```

Everything is working fine data is storing in the database and the stored value is also visible to the backend Edit user page. But, It is neither showing in the front end nor prefilled to the address form.

How should I make it work so that the stored value will be displayed at the frontend?
Any help will much be appreciated!

**EDIT:**  I am also using saved addresses for woocommerce plugin that allows users to save multiple addresses.

Comment: The fields with values are displayed in My account > Addresses > edit billing / edit shipping

Comment: Not displaying. That's the issue

Comment: I have tested your code on last WooCommerce version / storefront theme and they are displayed !

Comment: I am using the sage starter theme for WordPress with the latest version of woocommerce and facing that issue.
I am also using saved addresses for woocommerce plugin that allows users to save multiple addresses.